# Remove onclick event from img tag

Tags: javascript

Heres my code:

```
<div id="cmdt_1_1d" class="dt_state1" onclick="sel_test(this.id)">
<img id="cmdt_1_1i" onclick="dropit('cmdt_1_1');" src="/site/hitechpackaging/images/items/bags_menu.jpg ">
<span class="dt_link">
<a href="javascript://">BAGS</a>
</span>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I cannot modify this file, is there a way using javascript to disable the onclick from the img tag only.

I was using this script but it disable the onclick event from all images. But i want only from this component

```
var anchorElements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
// for (var i in anchorElements)
 //   anchorElements[i].onclick = function() {
       // alert(this.id);
 //       return false;
 //   }
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Edited:
Is there a way to stop the function dropit from executing, is it possible using javascript. On page load, etc.

another option is can i rename the img file using javascript??

Comment: You've already got the code to do it in your question. Perhaps your question isn't how to disable it so much as how to isolate this particular image without disabling all images and without knowing the id.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var eles = document.getElementById('cmdt_1_1d').getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0; i < eles.length; i++)
   eles[i].onclick = function() {
     return false;
   }
```

Comment: thanks Gabe its working fine but I want to know is there a way to disable all the img tag inside a div. Because there will be lots of image file and will dont know the names. Is it possible???

Comment: Nit pick: (though it is a good answer) there's no getElement_s_ById - there are only ever (supposed to be) one element per Id.

Comment: do you know the name of the div that they are in? CSS-selectors are very powerful - you can certainly do it as long as you know something about where the images will be. Something like `document.querySelectorAll("div#thatContainsImages img")` will get you a NodeList of all img tags descendant of that div.

Comment: @Gabe—that replaces the onclick property value with a new function, better to just set it to '' (empty string) so there is no listener at all (and there's a syntax error).

Comment: I'd suggest using `eles[i].onclick = null`. It will ensure that no onclick events are attached.

Answer (score 58):

```
document.getElementById('cmdt_1_1i').removeAttribute("onclick");
```

Comment: nice - I totally didn't even think of removeAttribute - that's probably the sanest way to do it, rather than intercept/overwrite it - just remove it!

Comment: Yes, unusual, but for "obstrusive" javascript it should work :-)

Comment: @Bergi—your definition of unobtrusive seems different to others, your answer is just plain JS. "Unobtrusive" javascript would wait for the document to load, would test to see if the element exists, then would then test to see if *removeAttribute* was supported before calling it.

Comment: @RobG: Yes, that's true. With "obtrusive" I meant the hardcoded on-event attributes in the html source.

Answer (score 8):

Lots of answers, but the simplest is:

```
document.getElementById('cmdt_1_1i').onclick = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
var badImage = document.getElementById("cmdt_1_1i");
badImage.onclick = null;
badImage.addEventlistener("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return null;
},true);
```

Comment: save my day, tks

Answer (score 0):

If you later need to restore the onclick property, you can save it in a field before overwriting it:

```
document.getElementById(id).saved=document.getElementById(id).onclick;
document.getElementById(id).onclick = '';
```

so that later you can restore it:

```
document.getElementById(id).onclick=document.getElementById(id).saved;
```

This can be useful especially in the case, in which the original onclick property contained some dynamically computed value.

Answer (score -1):

You can programmatically reassign event listeners. So in this case, it might look something like:

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll('#cmdt_1_1d img')
for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].onclick = function() => {}
}
```

...where the query above returns all of the `img` tags that are descendants of the element with ID `cmdt_1_1d`, and reassigns each of their `onclick` listeners to an empty function. Therefore no actions will take place when those images are clicked.

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!

Comment: Do not post an answer with merely codes. While your solution can be useful, you should also explain why the code will fix the problem that was described in the question