# HTML removing all events from element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some javascript functions in my main program(im not able to modify this code) and some of them are not needed. I want to add new javascript and disable unnecessary events(for example `onClick`). 
I tried someething like this:

```
function disableClickEvent(){
    var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        for (var key in toDisableMap) {
             if(elems[i].innerHTML == key ){
                 elems[i].unbind();
                 break;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

but there is an error (in console):

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: a[i].unbind is not a function disableClickEvent
```

I am not sure that `unbind` is right way for disable events. How is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: which version of jquery u r using ? you can use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) jquery version above 1.7 or same

Comment: Instead you can use `off()`

Comment: @MilanChheda There is the same error - `jQuery.Deferred exception: a[i].off is not a function`

Comment: `var elems = $('a')` to get the jquery object of all elements?

Comment: Are you using `jQuery.Deferred()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: jQuery  unbind don't work on onclick

Comment: @MilanChheda I am not using it

Comment: @XYZ so what should I use?

Comment: Try to watch this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712219/remove-onclick-event-from-img-tag

Comment: @KilianStinson to be honest im not sure but it is possible to use `elems[i].innerHTML` for get text

Comment: @tombobby after first click set the onclick of the element to return  false

Comment: @tombobby try $("elems[i]").prop('onclick',null);

Comment: @XYZ I tried it but 'onclick' event is still there

Comment: @tombobby added an answer.please check

Answer (score 0):

You're calling jQuery methods on objects returned by [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName). `getElementsByTagName` does not return back jQuery objects. You need to either do `$(elems[i]).unbind();` in your existing code or better off, find the anchor tags like `$("a", "body")` and then work with them

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the jQuery object in order to use `unbind()`.

I updated your snippet changing the methods to their jQuery counterparts.

```
function disableClickEvent() {
    var elems = $("a");
    elems.each(function() {
        for (var key in toDisableMap) {
            if ($(this).text() == key){
                $(this).prop('onclick',null).off('click');
                break;
            }
         }
    })
}
```

Comment: There is an error `jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).Text is not a function disableClickEvent`

Comment: @tombobby Oh my fault. It needs to be lowercase `.text()`

Comment: Are you sure that `unbind()` should works? It looks like `onClick` event is still there...

Comment: I've adopted `unbind` from your solution. Edited mine to use `prop` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
function disableClickEvent(){
    var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    $(elems[i]).off('click'); 
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="test1" style="cursor:pointer">Test1</a>
<br>
<a id="test2"  style="cursor:pointer">Test2</a>
<br>
<button onclick="disableClickEvent()" value="Disable">Disable</button>
```

When using .Off() you have to use Jquery object $(elems[i]).off('click');

Comment: `$(elems[i]).off('click');` does not clean events (there are still `onClick` action)

Answer (score 0):

Check this if it works.Used  `$(elems[i]).removeAttr('onclick');` to remove the click event from the anchor tag. Once the button pressed the click event from the anchor tag will be removed

```js
function disableClickEvent(){
  
    var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
         
         $(elems[i]).removeAttr('onclick');
         
       /* for (var key in toDisableMap) {
             if(elems[i].innerHTML == key ){
                 elems[i].unbind();
                 break;
             }
         }*/
    }
}

function clickevent(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("clicked")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="disableClickEvent()"> Remove events </button>

<a href="" onclick="clickevent(event)">Anchor tag click</a>
```