# Block Javascript function after 1 call

Tags: javascript

I am working on a multiple-choice question app and I am a database where I am storing the users answers. I just want to store the first answer they select to store it in the database. After the first selection, they can still click on the other answers to run the `checkAnswer()` but the `storeAnwserStats()` should not run. How can I do that?

[image]

**app.js**

```
  function storeAnwserStats(questionId, answerId){
      $.ajax({
        url : "/store_stats",
        type : "POST",
        data : JSON.stringify({
                  question_id: questionId,
                  answer_id:answerId, 
                }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
    })
    .done(function(data){
        console.log("After " +data["correct_answer"]);
    });
    }
    
    function checkAnswer(divSelected, answerId, questionId, isCorrect){
      if(isCorrect == 1){
        divSelected.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      }
      else{
        divSelected.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
      storeAnwserStats(questionId, answerId)
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyZfY.png
```

Comment: you could use a boolean variable it is at the beginning false and then when you run you logic set it to true. Wrap you logic inside a condition and check for this boolean

Comment: I think it better to do it inside `storeAnwserStats`, where you store answer. And better to show it's code here

Comment: The main part of it should be done server-side. Yes, you can additionally stop your client from re-sending useless data, but for security and data integrity, the server-side is the important one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do multiple things for this.

**METHOD 1**

**Disable the options**: After the person has answered you can make the the sibling options disabled.

**DOWNSIDE**: the person can make the element enabled again by inspecting the element.

**METHOD 2**

**Server side validation**: check from server side if the answer has been answered or not on each call.

**DOWNSIDE**: server calls are increased.

**METHOD 3**

**Remove the onclick along with onClick**: After the person has answered you can make the the sibling options disabled **AND** [remove the onClick call from them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712219/remove-onclick-event-from-img-tag).

**DOWNSIDE**: Not sure of any yet.

**EDIT 1**

*Server side validation is still important*

Even after you do all those things above if the person really wants to be *fishy*
they can still send answers to your server by calling the function from **console**.

suppose in the **OnClick** function of the option you are calling your **storeAnwserStats()**, and since they are client side JS files I can easily check it and send the request by going to the console and typing **storeAnwserStats(question_id, answer_id)** (and question ID can be seen in the network tab)

good luck!

Comment: Server side validation is not an option, it's an absolute must. You can additionally avoid the request with client-side logic.

Comment: Potentially true or fictitious story: there once was an online university course, where a slightly invalid answer format would trigger the `checkAnswer`, leaking the correct answer, but not lock the user's answer server side. I hear good grades did not require much effort that semester.

Comment: @Bergi You are right, Just updated the answer.

Comment: @ASDFGerte seems like one can do that manually, just by calling the function on their own XD

Comment: In the story, it wasn't quite that easy (but still not hard lol). The answer wasn't stored client-side, but always included in a submit response, even if the answer was rejected because of an invalid format, allowing to answer the question again afterwards. It's just a tip, that if there is even a remote chance, that the user isn't your best friend (and maybe has own interests), then the server should assume the client is some three-headed hydra anglerfish mutation, whose whole purpose is to sabotage you.